# Looping through strings 1 character at a time in MIPS

Tags: string, loops, assembly, mips, mips32

I'm having issues grasping the concept of string and characters in MIPS. If I'm trying to loop through two strings, and concatenate two characters at a time, how would I do this?

Lets say I have

```
String1 = "St"
String2 = "ack"
```

How could I loop through to get

```
Sa, Sc, Sk, ta, tc, tk
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you write us the pseudocode you think would do it, and whatever MIPS code you have so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wasn't able to figure it out, the MIPS environment I used had something built in apparently.

Answer (score 0):

the most easy way to do this:

1)write the program with C.

2)compile it with GCC with flags "-S", and use "> xx.S" to store the assembly code to a file.

3)extract the assembly codes from "xx.S".

Comment: This only works on a Mips machine, as I don't have a cross compiler.

Comment: maybe you can try 'buildroot' a dummy tool.

Comment: From what I've read, it's extremely difficult to make a GCC cross compiler from x86 to MIPS?

Comment: you can just make binutils & partial gcc (make all-gcc, make install all-gcc) that don't need the libc, and I have succeed to it.